# Tkinter resizing images in labels arranged in a grid

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

To start, I'm totally new to Tkinter and am trying to make a Raspberry Pi Media Player of sorts...

I grab the directories of all .mp4 files on a USB drive, and use PIL to put the thumbnails of the videos into a 3x3 grid of labels, with the grid inside of a frame (frame2 in the code).

Right now, with the thumbnails of varying sizes, the labels are also inconsistently sized. Also, only the top-right portion of larger thumbnails are displayed, rather than the entire image.

How can I to scale and fit the thumbnails into consistently sized labels, in grid form?

Here is part of my code (It's quite large so I try to include only the relevant parts):

```py
import tkinter as tk

from subprocess import Popen
from time import sleep
import os
from random import randint

import imageio
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from pathlib import Path

#putting 100th frame of video with 'path' into the label
def pack_thumbnail(path, label):
    #this is probably not a good way to do this
    video = imageio.get_reader(path)
    for i in range(100):
        try:
            image = video.get_next_data()
        except:
            video.close()
            break
    frame_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(image))
    label.config(image=frame_image)
    label.image = frame_image

window = tk.Tk()
window.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

frame1 = tk.Frame(master=window, width=200, height=100, bg="white")
frame1.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.LEFT)
#frame2 contains the grid of labels
frame2 = tk.Frame()

for i in range(3):
    frame2.columnconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=75)
    frame2.rowconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=50)
    
    for j in range(0, 3):
        frame = tk.Frame(master=frame2, relief=tk.RAISED, borderwidth=1)
        frame.grid(row=i, column=j, padx=5, pady=5)

        #path to video to get thumbnail (i only have 3 videos so i randomize it)
        vid_path=f"/media/pi/{os.listdir('/media/pi/')[0]}/{folder_name}/{videos[randint(0, 2)]}"

        label = tk.Label(master=frame, text=f"Row {i}\nColumn {j}")
        pack_thumbnail(vid_path, label)
        label.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
frame2.pack()

window.bind("<Escape>", lambda x: window.destroy())
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Image.thumbnail()` to resize the image:

```py
# putting 100th frame of video with 'path' into the label
def pack_thumbnail(path, label):
    with imageio.get_reader(path) as video:
        image = video.get_data(100)  # use get_date() instead of get_next_data()
    w, h = 200, 200  # thumbnail size
    image = Image.fromarray(image)
    image.thumbnail((w, h)) # resize the image
    frame_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    label.config(image=frame_image, width=w, height=h)
    label.image = frame_image
```

Comment: images fit in the labels now, thanks! is the w, h for thumbnail size in pixels or text units?

Comment: They are in pixels.